# Getting attendees list without authorisation

Tags: google-calendar-api

How can I get attendees list from the google calendar via API, without authorisation?

On my website I want to list all attendees of an Google Calendar event. When using getJson command with a simpe Api key, the attendees are hidden, except the organizer. When using OAuth, all attendees are visible, but I have to go through the Google's log-in window. Is there any way to see the full attendees list without any log-in?

Comment: I think it is because the moment you have added the said event, it needs authorization as what stated in the [Calendar API documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert). Could be a reason that you needed an authorization as well in accessing data from that event. Although it was not stated in the [Events: get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get) method, but you are accessing the event which is inserted with authorization, so, I don't think you can get a calendar event details without authorization.

Comment: After some research I've learned that what I want can be achieved with server to server authorisation= my website will do the authorisation in the background, and then it will be able get all attendees of an event. I am not a professional programmer (and not going to be), so can anyone share a complete server-to-server authorisation example in javascript, followed by an event().get (or whatever there has to be), in similar way like this was done here: "https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js" ? I understand how to set up the application authorisation in google developper console.

Answer (score 0):

What  you need to understand first is the difference between public and private data.  Public data is data that is not owned by anyone.  The Google calendar holiday calendars for example are public user data anyone can access them no one owns them.   On the other hand my personal calendar is a private user calendar you can not access it without my permission.

So if you want to access a Google calendar and see the events on the calendar without being logged in you will need to set the calendar public and then get a public api key from the google developers site.   This will be read only you wont be able to make any changes only see them.

If you check [events get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get)  you will notice it does not require any authorization to use it.  However if the calendar you are checking is not set to public you will be told you dont have access.